# How do i keep empty columns while concating in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

So I have 2 dataframes both with empty columns but that is intentional. So how do i keep the empty columns when i concat them on the same axis?

```
abdc  123  *nan*

1     2    *nan*
```

Both the dfs look similar. So for eg, `pd.concat([df,df])` removes the empty column
I want the df to look like this

```
abdc  123  *nan*  abdc  123  *nan*

1     2    *nan*  1     2    *nan*
```

So is this possible to do?

Comment: This code works for me as expected and keeps empty columns: `df = pd.DataFrame({'abdc' : [1], '123' : [2], np.nan : [np.nan]})`
and then `df = pd.concat([df,df,df], axis=1)`. It also keeps empty columns when exporting to csv or excel . I have done something similar for a project.

Comment: @DavidErickson oh i hadn't tried it with np.nan.  Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Take `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['abdc', 1], 'B':[123,2], 'C':[np.nan, np.nan]})`. Then do this: `pd.concat([df,df], axis=1)`. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'abcd':[1],"123":[2],"*nan*":[np.nan]})
df
   abcd  123  *nan*
0     1    2    NaN

pd.concat([df,df],axis=1)
   abcd  123  *nan*  abcd  123  *nan*
0     1    2    NaN     1    2    NaN
```